# Web scraping a table following a search loop

Tags: excel, vba

The table's HTML is:

```
<TABLE   border="1" width="100%">

    <TR class="row0">
        <TD style="width: 30%"><strong>TITLE</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 40%">UNIQUE</TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%"><strong>BU Assigned</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%">REMOVED</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR class="row1">
        <TD style="width: 30%"><strong>Account Number</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 40%">TARGET INFORMATION</TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%"><strong>BU Logged</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%">REMOVED</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR class="row0">
        <TD style="width: 30%"><strong>3rd Party Reference</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 40%">REMOVED</TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%"><strong>Date Received</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%">REMOVED</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR class="row1">
        <TD style="width: 30%"><strong>Subject</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 40%">REMOVED</TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%"><strong>Date Logged</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%">REMOVED</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR class="row0">
        <TD style="width: 30%"><strong>Reason</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 40%">REMOVED</TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%"><strong>Last Action Date</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%">REMOVED</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR  class="row1" >
        <TD style="width: 30%"><strong>Status</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 40%">REMOVED</TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%"><strong>Date Resolved</strong></TD>
        <TD style="width: 15%">REMOVED</TD>
    </TR>

</TABLE>
```

I am searching through all the tables in the page, trying to pull "Target INFORMATION" after locating "UNIQUE" which i assume should be in Row(0).Cells(1) but this gives me runtime error 91 - Object Variable or With block variable not set.

However when i search through for Row(0).Cells(0) being "TITLE" the code will find the table and i can proceed happily. Anyone know a way around this? I have tried changing the cell number all the way to 10 just in case there were some empty cells that I didn't notice. Note: there may well be multiple tables where 0,0 has the same title the only unique field is UNIQUE which is obtained from my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out an answer and feel silly for not getting it straight away:

```
Dim tbls, tbl

    Set tbls = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    CR = Workbooks("My Book").Worksheets("My Sheet").Range("A" & RowCnt).Value

    For Each tbl In tbls
        If tbl.Rows(0).Cells(0).innertext = "TITLE" Then
            PCR = tbl.Rows(0).Cells(1).innertext
            If CR = PCR Then
            'my code inserted
            Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Really annoying that it was this simple and no idea how I was unable to search directly for Rows(0).Cells(1) with my If statement.

**Full code:**

```
Private Sub test()

Dim IE As Object
Dim RowCnt As Long
Dim CIS, AN, CR As String

RowCnt = 2

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

Do Until Workbooks("My Book").Worksheets("My Sheet").Range("A" & RowCnt).Value = ""

CIS = Workbooks("My book").Worksheets("My sheet").Range("C" & RowCnt).Value

IE.Navigate "First part" & CIS & "Second Part"

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Dim tbls, tbl

    Set tbls = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    CR = Workbooks("My book").Worksheets("My sheet").Range("A" & RowCnt).Value

    For Each tbl In tbls
        If tbl.Rows(0).Cells(1).innertext = CR Then
            AN = tbl.Rows(1).Cells(1).innertext
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

RowCnt = RowCnt + 1

Loop


End Sub
```