# Importing data from a password protected website and with no id for the table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to import data from a password protected website(https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Ports/Home.html), i do have the username and the password.

I've tried this code made by Dick in this website: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/11/29/html-tables/
but it doesn't work and get stuck every time i adjust it.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Home.html"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.UserName.Value = "username"
.Password.Value = "password"
.submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Port/tangermed/Dashboard.html"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
clip.PutInClipboard
Sheet1.Select
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I really appreciate any help from you.
Thank you.

Comment: It will not work, you need the line that is commented out, as ieApp is never created or no site is navigated to. `Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer` then `ieApp.navigate...`

Comment: It's already in the code ! and it doesn't work!

Comment: Please specify which line causes an error and include the details of the error.

Comment: it stops at  {Dim clip As DataObject}  !!

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840179/6387479) an example of looping through all tables checking the first cell for it's inner text